# How to handle comments and posts with mongoose in a mean app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongoose, mean

This is my first Stackoverflow post, i'll try to make it simple. I have to build a social network with the mean stack for my school. Pretty amazingg technology but i can't find how to use properly the function population of mongoose for linking comments to posts. My comments are saved in the database but appared in all the posts on my first page. Can you tell me what i done wrong ? Thanks in advance !

Here's my view post

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form ng-submit="pst.sendPost()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Your post</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="share your thoughts..." ng-model="pst.newpst.text">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Post</button>
</form><br>

<div ng-repeat="post in pst.posts | orderBy: '-'">
    <div class="well">{{post.text}}
        <br><form ng-submit="pst.sendComment(post._id)">
                    <br><div class="well">
                        <label for="comment"></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="comment" placeholder="comment..." ng-model="pst.newcmt.text">
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat="comment in pst.comments| orderBy: '+'" class="alert alert-info" role="alert">{{comment.text}}<br>{{comment._id}}
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="pst.removeComment(comment._id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="pst.removePost(post._id)">Remove Post</button>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's my angular controller

```js
angular.module('app')
    .controller('PostController', function($scope, $http) {
        var _this = this;

        this.getPosts = function() {
            $http.get('/api/posts')
                .then(function(res){
                    _this.posts = res.data;
                });
        };

        this.getPosts();

        this.removePost = function(id) {
            $http.delete('/api/posts/' + id)
                .then(function(){
                    _this.getPosts();
                });
        };


        this.sendPost = function() {
            if (!this.newpst || !this.newpst.text)
                return;
            $http.post('api/posts', this.newpst)
                .then(function(){
                    _this.getPosts();
                });
            this.newpst = {};
        };

        this.updatePost = function(id) {
            $http.post('/api/posts/' + id)
                .then(function(){
                    _this.getPosts();
                });
        };


        this.getComments = function() {
            $http.get('/api/comments')
                .then(function(res){
                    _this.comments = res.data;
                });
        };

        this.getComments();

        this.removeComment = function(id) {
            console.log(id);
            $http.delete('/api/comments/' + id)
                .then(function(){
                    _this.getComments();
                });
        };


        this.sendComment = function(id) {
            this.newcmt.post = id
            console.log(this.newcmt)
            $http.post('api/comments', this.newcmt)
                .then(function(){
                    _this.getComments();
                });
            this.newcmt = {};
        };

        this.updateComment = function(id) {
            $http.post('/api/comments/' + id)
                .then(function(){
                    _this.getComments();
                });
        };

    })
```

Here's my post.model.js

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', {

text: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
image: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},

comment1: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Comment'
}]
});
```

my routes_posts.js

```js
var Post = require('./post.model');

module.exports = function(app) {

    app.delete('/api/posts/:id', function(req, res) {
        Post.remove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err) {
            (err ? res.send(err) : res.status(200).send());
        });
    });



    app.get('/api/posts', function(req, res) {
        Post.find({})
            .populate('comment')
            .exec(function(err, posts){
                (err ? console.log(err) : res.json(posts))
        })
    });




    app.post('/api/posts', function(req, res) {
        Post.create(req.body, function(err) {
            (err ? res.send(err) : res.status(200).send());
        });
    });
};
```

my comment.model.js

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', {
    text: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },

    post: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Post',
    }
});
```

my routes_comment.js

```js
var Comment = require('./comment.model');
var Post = require('../posts/post.model')

module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get('/api/comments', function(req, res) {
        Post.find({})
            .populate('post_id')
            .exec(function(err, comments){
                (err ? console.log(err) : res.json(comments))
            })
    });

    app.post('/api/comments', function(req, res) {
        console.log(req)
        Comment.create(req.body, function( err) {
            (err ? res.send(err) : res.status(200).send());
        });
    });

    app.delete('/api/comments/:id', function(req, res) {
        Comment.remove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err) {
            (err ? res.send(err) : res.status(200).send());
        });
    });
};
```

Thanks !

Comment: I am missing mongooses `Post` model. Do you have only the angular one?

Comment: Damn you are right, i posted twice the same code. I'll try to edit.

Comment: This is it, i corrected it.

Comment: Did you try to check what comments are hold in `post.comment1` post by mongoose console (like robomongo)? Are there all required comments?